# How can I resolve these 'cryptsetup: WARNING' messages following Ubuntu server upgrade?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-server

After recently upgrading the packages on my Ubuntu 12.04 server I received a couple of warnings in relation to cryptsetup.

My update steps were:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

The warnings I received were:

```
cryptsetup: WARNING: failed to detect canonical device of /dev/xvda
cryptsetup: WARNING: could not determine root device from /etc/fstab
```

There seems to be very little documentation on these warnings. Do I need to take notice of them and if so how?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

If cryptsetup is not involved in your boot process and your server boots the way it did before, then you can safely ignore these messages.

You should check your apt logs which process causes these message to appear, it should be something involved with `update-initramfs`/`mkinitramfs`. One reason why users get these messages is when they have configured something else than UUIDs to identify devices in fstab while using cryptsetup (device names are supposed to be faster if you're chasing after milliseconds of boot time improvements and only have one drive).

I was looking for an answer to suppress these messages in my setup where I only use cryptsetup for external drives.

Answer (score 0):

My own encounter with this error message seemed to be related to an inconsistency in my configs of the vg name given to the lvm partition upon which I had put my system.

I had used vgrename to use a different group label for my logical volumes. But this left incorrect vg references in at least two other places (fstab and grub.cfg) and possibly more besides.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/994778/how-get-ubuntu-to-boot-after-reducing-size-of-encrypted-logical-volume/995148#995148